# jQWidget - jqxGrid multiple header rows such as jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid, jqxgrid, jqwidget

I would like to display multiple header rows such that I the top header row group would span a set of lower header row column names.  I know you can do this in jqGrid.  An example of it is:

```
jQuery("#samples").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', { 
 useColSpanStyle: true, 
 groupHeaders:[ 
    {startColumnName: 'totalweight', numberOfColumns: 6, titleText: 'Count'}, 
    {startColumnName: 'bellyburst', numberOfColumns: 3, titleText: 'Damaged'}, 
    {startColumnName: 'a', numberOfColumns: 6, titleText: 'Weight'}, 
    {startColumnName: 'fish', numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: 'Quality'}, 
 ] 
});
```

Comment: Is Triand jqgrid same as JQWidget JQXGrid? I am confused between the two.

Comment: @cleanbold No both are different tools. jQGrid and JQX Grid is not same.

Answer (score 0):

Never saw such a feature in jqxGrid. If your grid is pretty static, you could try to add that row manually, but it can become a cumbersome solution. If you try that, be sure to put your html outside the jqxGrid div, because too much thing are moving inside that div. Them, skin your html, so it looks like it is part of the grid.

Another solution could be to use sub title. You can archive that when you define a column. You can add a renderer, which is a function that returns an header. I didn't try, but I'm pretty sure you can return HTML in your header, and build subtitles.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use column hierarchy option introduced in jQWidget JQX grid. Please see the below example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title id='Description'>This sample illustrates the Columns Hierarchy feature of jqxGrid.
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.sort.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.filter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.columnsresize.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.columnsreorder.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.pager.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.edit.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxpanel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcheckbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/demos.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // prepare the data
            var source =
            {
                datatype: "xml",
                datafields: [
                     { name: 'SupplierName', type: 'string' },
                     { name: 'Quantity', type: 'number' },
                     { name: 'OrderDate', type: 'date' },
                     { name: 'OrderAddress', type: 'string' },
                     { name: 'Freight', type: 'number' },
                     { name: 'Price', type: 'number' },
                     { name: 'City', type: 'string' },
                     { name: 'ProductName', type: 'string' },
                     { name: 'Address', type: 'string' }
                ], 
                url: '../sampledata/orderdetailsextended.xml',
                root: 'DATA',
                record: 'ROW'
            };
            var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source, {
                loadComplete: function () {
                }
            });
            // create jqxgrid.
            $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
            {
                width: 850,
                source: dataAdapter,
                pageable: true,
                autorowheight: true,
                altrows: true,
                columnsresize: true,
                columns: [
                  { text: 'Supplier Name', cellsalign: 'center', align: 'center', datafield: 'SupplierName', width: 110 },
                  { text: 'Name', columngroup: 'ProductDetails', cellsalign: 'center', align: 'center', datafield: 'ProductName', width: 120 },
                  { text: 'Quantity', columngroup: 'ProductDetails', datafield: 'Quantity', cellsformat: 'd', cellsalign: 'center', align: 'center', width: 80 },
                  { text: 'Freight', columngroup: 'OrderDetails', datafield: 'Freight', cellsformat: 'd', cellsalign: 'center', align: 'center', width: 100 },
                  { text: 'Order Date', columngroup: 'OrderDetails', cellsalign: 'center', align: 'center', cellsformat: 'd', datafield: 'OrderDate', width: 100 },
                  { text: 'Order Address', columngroup: 'OrderDetails', cellsalign: 'center', align: 'center', datafield: 'OrderAddress', width: 100 },
                  { text: 'Price', columngroup: 'ProductDetails', datafield: 'Price', cellsformat: 'c2', align: 'center', cellsalign: 'center', width: 70 },
                  { text: 'Address', columngroup: 'Location', cellsalign: 'center', align: 'center', datafield: 'Address', width: 120 },
                  { text: 'City', columngroup: 'Location', cellsalign: 'center', align: 'center', datafield: 'City', width: 80 }
                ],
                columngroups: 
                [
                  { text: 'Product Details', align: 'center', name: 'ProductDetails' },
                  { text: 'Order Details', parentgroup: 'ProductDetails', align: 'center', name: 'OrderDetails' },
                  { text: 'Location', align: 'center', name: 'Location' }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body class='default'>
    <div id="jqxgrid">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```